# Google Colab suddenly slow

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm a new man in Deep learning and Google Colab. I'm trying to run this repo on Google Colab 
https://github.com/harvitronix/five-video-classification-methods
But when I running extract_features.py, after 30 minutes, google Colab suddenly extreme slow, from ~2s/it to ~ 30s/it. As you can see in the picture below. It's my fault or it's a problem of GG Colab and how to fix it?

[image: Google Colab so slow]

Comment: Here is the answer [Change Runtime type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60458910/9454010)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Code uses over 25GB of Ram and Crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60442493/my-code-uses-over-25gb-of-ram-and-crashes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out my problem, it's Colab Problem, K80 GPU Memory decrease from 11.5GB to 500mb (randomly), it depends on Colab and we can't fix it!

Answer (score 2):

Google Colab will run slow if you use too much runtime, try having small sessions and also terminate all sessions not in use to speed up. Use a TPU or GPU based on your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google drive space to load the dataset, firstly download it to local colab notebook runtime space, I simply unzip the dataset into local runtime space and it resulted in quicker executions.

This trick can be applied if you are already using a GPU runtime and still want faster executions.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would like to mention basic troubleshooting steps like check you internet connection and make sure you are on a stable Wi-Fi or wired internet connection.

Also if someone else is also on your network and they are downloading a heavy file (say a movie) ask them to pause/stop it for a while.

Apart from these basic steps I would recommend you to follow the below mentioned if you haven't already:

1. Go to **Runtime** in Menu Bar.
2. Select **Change runtime type**
3. Under *Hardware accelerator* drop down menu select **GPU**.
4. Click on **Save**

The notebook will buffer for a second or so while showing *Allocating* on right side of the Menu Bar. This should solve your issue.
Apart from that I would like you to go through the basic introduction of using colab by following this link -> [Colaboratory Welcome Link](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb)

Comment: I figure out my problem, it's Colab Problem, K80 GPU Memory decrease from 11.5GB to 500mb, it depends on Colab and we can't fix it