# My Code uses over 25GB of Ram and Crashes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

So I'm using Extra Trees Classifier in order to find the feature importance in my dataset, it consists of 13 columns and about 10 million rows. I have ran elliptic envelope on it, isolation forest and everything was fine, it even took less than 10 GB. I ran my code on jupyter note book and it gave me memory error even when I set it to low_memory=True. I tried Google COlab which has about 25GB of memory and still crashed, I'm very confused right now.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline


from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier 


from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)



# Loading First Dataframe

link = '...'

fluff, id = link.split('=')
print (id) # Verify that you have everything after '='
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('Final After Simple Filtering.csv')  
df = pd.read_csv('Final After Simple Filtering.csv',index_col=None,low_memory=True)
#df = df.astype(float)


ExtraT = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators = 100,bootstrap=False,n_jobs=1) 

y=df['Power_kW']

del df['Power_kW']

X=df


ExtraT.fit(X,y)

feature_importance = ExtraT.feature_importances_ 

feature_importance_normalized = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in ExtraT.estimators_], axis = 1)

plt.bar(X.columns, feature_importance) 
plt.xlabel('Lable') 
plt.ylabel('Feature Importance') 
plt.title('Parameters Importance') 
plt.show()
```

Thank you

Comment: ***"...and still crashed"*** - Any particular error message?

Comment: on Jupyter Notebook it says: " MemoryError: could not allocate 28806479872 bytes`"


and on Google Colab : "Your session crashed after using all available RAM in Google Collab"

Comment: Please share the entire error message in your post itself. Since we can’t have an easy [mcve], have you done any profiling?

Comment: @AMC it seems that when I set the max_depth anywhere below or equal10 it started to run normally, anything about that just gives me memory error. I have also set n_jobs=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same Error before and i solved it.

**Change Runtime type** 
GPU is Faster more than CPU , so it will help. But How to Do that ? Follow this steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Be sure that you use 25GB not 12GB of RAM .
Don't forget that Colab is free and limited Edition.
If still have a problem , tell me and i will help you ASAP.