# How can I increase the use of RAM in Colab?

Tags: performance, process, google-colaboratory, ram

I'm just using 1.49 out of 25 GB of memory from Colab while running a script? How can I use the maximum memory capacity to speed up the process?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Possible help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60458910/9454010

Comment: I've already done that, same performance. any clue?

Comment: They offered to upgrade the ram when  colab VM crashed due to low ram. But how to crash it ? just download huge dataset and unzip it ...etc , Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Data processing is done using a CPU or a GPU (or both of them at the same time). For the CPU, its speed can be measured using 2 metrics : Instructions per Second (IPS), or Floating Point Operations per Second (FLOPS). The architecture of a CPU and the number of cores affect its speed. Nowadays, GPU's are heavily used in data processing due to their bandwidth advantage over CPU's, there are a lot of other reasons, you can look them up here : [CPU Vs GPU](https://medium.com/@shachishah.ce/do-we-really-need-gpu-for-deep-learning-47042c02efe2)
So in order to speed up the data processing, make sure you're using Colab's GPU to run tests, while RAM holds all the data and variables of your current session. If you want to use all the RAM available, you simply need to use a bigger dataset as mentionned by @[AEM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9454010/aem) (more data = more RAM usage).
If you want to see the effects of more data on the RAM, you can try this simple code :

```
data = []
while(1): 
  data.append('1234')
```

This infinite loop makes you add more & more data into a list until you hit the maximum usage of RAM (Colab might crash eventually), hope this helps.

Comment: It feels like Google patched this and it no longer works. I'm stuck at 12GBs

Comment: @CsepreghyAndras i guess so, i tried to upgrade the RAM with a new Colab account (not my main), and it didn't work.