# Google Colab become slower with the same code sometimes. What is the possible reasons?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am training a CNN model with Google Colab's GPU through pytorch.  My question is, even though running with the same code, it gets about three times slower sometimes(30s -> 90s in my case).

I've tried restart runtime(it clears all local variable but keep files), it doesn't work

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391657/google-colab-suddenly-slow)    post, however, I've checked my GPU status, it works well with 11.5GB.

Sometimes it goes normal after disconnect it for a while though, I still want to figure out what can be the possible reason of it.

Comment: Please share a self contained notebook that reproduces the problem. Are you reading data files from Drive? Often, Drive performance varies significantly, so you may try copying files to the local disk first.

Comment: @BobSmith I'm reading files in local disk, and also the slow down problem is occured in the training process only, that's why I confused.

Answer (score 2):

Guys I think I found the possible answer [here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#usage-limits)

So it might be the limit of Google Colab itself. Due to their policy, sometimes you'll get fewer computation resources, which slower down the process even though no change in any code.